# How to debug a web application accessed through another web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, debugging

We have an old VB / ASP.NET web application. Most of our software was recently rewritten using C#, MVC and all sorts of other modern bells and whistles but one of the old VB applications will not be rewritten.

I need the new login page to redirect them to the old application, which I've done... mostly. I'd login and in my dev console in the browser I was seeing a 500 error when it tries to redirect to the old application. But the page would stay on the login page and not navigate anywhere.

Fixed that 500 error, now nothing shows up in the dev console and the page still doesn't redirect anywhere.

I'd like to debug the old VB code that's supposed to "catch" this redirect, but since the application starts in the new C# rewrite (with VS2013, compared to '08 for the VB application) I don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Modern versions of Visual Studio can open VS2008 projects and solutions fine - VS2015 has full support for .NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5, so you should be able to open the VB.NET application as-is, start it locally and debug it.

If it only fails in production you can install the Visual Studio Remote Debugger on the server and connect through the LAN by using <kbd>Debug > Attach to Process...</kbd> and specifying the machine name. You might have to fight some DCOM permissions settings, fwiw.

Comment: The OP mentioned that the old code is VB rather than VB.NET. Either the tags/title are wrong, or the post.

Comment: @JustinNiessner OP mentions "VB / ASP.NET" and "'08" - given that VB6 has nothing to do with ASP.NET (or even Classic ASP, which was VBScript) I'm certain the OP is referring to a VB9 project in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: @JustinNiessner I did mean VB.NET, I just didn't want ot sound redundant and say "VB.NET / ASP.NET"

Comment: @Dai Whenever I try to open an older solution in a newer version, I get prompted for a "one-way upgrade". Perhaps it's ignorance, but I don't think I'm comfortable doing that- our applications are set up in a rather convoluted and confusing manner (I'm relatively new here though). Not confident everything will still play nice if I do the upgrade?

Comment: @sab669 I suggest you create a new branch in your source-control repo for this investigation, so you can make changes to the project files without fear of long-term consequence.